# Access to Doctrine in Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have two Entity class: House and Car.

in Entity House class i have method:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\HouseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * House
 */
class House {
//...
  public function getRandomCar()
  {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $car = $em->getRepository('AcmeCarBundle:Car')->find(rand(0,100));

      return $car->getName();
  }
}
```

but i dont have access to Doctrine in my Entity House class. How can i make it?

Comment: Do this in a repository class.

Comment: I know, but how can i use Doctrine in Entity and others class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the function `getRandomCar` in your `CarRepository` (you'll have to create it)

A simple rule is to never, ever write queries inside an entity (car, house....)

Read more about [Repositories](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

<kbd>**Car.php**</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="car")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\CarBundle\Entity\CarRepository")
 */
class Car 
{
}
```

<kbd>**CarRepository.php**</kbd>

```
class CarRepository extends EntityRepository  
{
    public function getRandomCar() 
    {
        $qb = $this->createQuery('c');
        $qb->where('c.id = :id')
            ->setParameters(array('id' => rand(0,100)))
            ->getQuery();

        return $qb->execute();
    }
}
```

Then in your <kbd>**Controller**</kbd>,

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$car = $em->$em->getRepository('AcmeCarBundle:Car')->getRandomCar();
$car->getName();
```

Comment: ok, thanks but how can i use Doctrine in Entity and others class? this is not possible?

Comment: Read my response, you can't and should not use doctrine entity manager in your Entities. Therefore, you can use it in your Controllers, and all other classes (services...) but not in your Entity class

Comment: But i dont use Controller. I would like use this method in Sonata Admin